# Error on Linking a C library: libsodium.la file not recognized

Tags: c, mingw, libsodium

I want to use a library in C so I've downloaded it (libsodium) and I'm trying to use it with a simple program and I cannot make Codeblocks to recognise it.
I get the following error

```
    libsodium.la: file not recognized: file format not recognized
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My Specs:
Architecture x64
Codeblocks
Windows 10
MinGW

I'm using the pre-builts available in the library resources and copying them into MinGW local folder and binding them to the linker following a codeblocks tutorial

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Was the prebuilt library also x64?

Did you link with the .la file instead of the .a file by mistake?

In Code::Blocks add the path where `libsodium.a` is to the library search path and add `sodium` as a library (or `-lsodium` as linker flag)

Have you tried building libsodium yourself? If you have MSYS2 it's not that hard:

```
# change the following line to the location where you want to install libsodium
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
./configure --prefix=$INSTALLPREFIX --enable-blocking-random LDFLAGS="-Wl,--as-needed -lssp" &&
make install-strip &&
echo Success
```